# realloc memory in string array in C

Tags: c, c99, strcpy

I'm trying to satisfy valgrind and come up with a nice implementation, but I'm coming across a snag. Essentially what I'm trying to do is reduce two strings in an array to one. Let's say `arr` contains

```
{ "One", "Two", "Three" }
```

And that the memory allocation for each string has been done as it should be (a la `arr[1] = malloc(strlen("one") + 1)` and `strcpy(arr[1], "One")`.

I do some string manipulation and try to do:

> strcpy(arr[1],"OneTwo");

and remove arr[2] but this is inherently problematic because the memory allocation for arr[1] has changed. Something tells me that doing malloc again would be bad.

I could do `realloc` but that would require either freeing arr[2] and shifting everything after it down one space and realloc'ing. I could also do `arr[2] = NULL` but valgrind disagrees.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I'm trying to satisfy valgrind " - erm no, you are trying to write code that isn't flawed with memory overwrite errors!

Comment: First you should give us the complete declaration. The snipset makes a whole lot of difference if you have `char arr[n][m]`, `char *arr[]` or `char const*arr[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reallocate `arr[1]` and append `arr[2]` to the end of the string, then free `arr[2]` (and set arr[2] = NULL to avoid confusion later).

Answer (score 2):

Why would `realloc`ing `arr[1]` require any modification of anything else?

```
strcpy( arr[1] = realloc( arr[1], sizeof "OneTwo" ), "OneTwo" );
free( arr[2] );
arr[2] = NULL;
```

Looks good to me. There's nothing after `arr[2]` here so no shifting to do. If there were, then yes, removing from the middle of any array demands that you shift down the following elements.

Comment: doesn't that assume that arr[1] (arr[i]) was malloc'ed? i.e. can the compiler layout { "One", "Two", "Three" } as non-malloc'ed memory?

Comment: @Mitch: He specifically said that the strings were malloced in the first place. It's not clear from his description using literals, true.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: ah yes, so he did, but I wondered if this is obvious to the poster. There's allocated and malloced!

Comment: This assumes that realloc succeeds. Fine for demonstration, but not so good in production.

Comment: @dmckee: In principle yes, but on my platform at least (OS X) the system would rather SIGSTOP your process and present a dialog asking the user to free up memory, than allow `malloc` to fail.

Comment: This seems to fail valgrind however:

`char * ptr = realloc(arr[1], sizeof(char *) * (strlen("OneTwo"));`
    `strcpy(ptr, "OneTwo");`
    `free(arr[2]);`
    `arr[2] = NULL;`

Comment: @Rio: Why are you multiplying `sizeof(char *) * (strlen("OneTwo"))`? Why did you create a new variable `ptr` instead of modifying `arr[1]`? And how does it fail?